# Where are HTTPS Everywhere rules stored in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, https-everywhere

I am using Google Chrome on Windows 7. I've installed HTTPS Everywhere extension and I want to add my own custom rule.

According to [this document](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/rulesets) it should be stored in a `HTTPSEverywhereUserRules` directory somewhere on my disk. Unfortunately I cannot find it.

Do you have any idea where to look?

Answer (score 5):

Rules defined through the user interface are added in to the extension's local storage: 
`Local Storage/chrome-extension_gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp_0.localstorage` in your Chrome profile directory¹. This is an SQLite database, if you care to edit it manually.

You can also define rules manually (thanks to [MCL](https://superuser.com/a/689518) for the tip). Current versions of Chrome refuse to load an extension if it's been modified, so you need to either make a copy of the extension outside of the Chrome profile directory or update Chrome's stored signature after modifying the extension.

Either way, go to the extension's directory, which is `Extensions/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp/2014.9.11_0` in the Chrome profile directory¹ (replace `2014.9.11_0` by the version you have installed). If you choose to update the signature, you'll need to modify the files `_metadata/computed_hashes.json` and `_metadata/verified_contents.json`; I don't know what exactly you need to update or how. If you choose to make a copy, copy the `gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp` directory outside of your profile, uninstall the extension, and drag-and-drop the directory containing the outside copy onto the Extensions page in Chrome.

In the extension directory, there is a file called `rules_list.js` containing a reference to the default ruleset library. Add yours:

```
var rule_list = [
"rules/default.rulesets",
"rules/personal.rulesets",
];
```

Create a file called `personal.rulesets` in the `rules` subdirectory. From then on, to modify rules, edit that file. The content of this file should be something like this:

```
<rulesetlibrary>
<ruleset name="Example ruleset">
  <target host="*.example.com" />
  <target host="*.example.net" />
  <rule from="http:" to="https:" />
</ruleset>
</rulesetlibrary>
```

Each ruleset can be enabled or disabled independently through the user interface.

To make HTTPS Everywhere reload your rules, go to the Tools → Extensions page. Untick the “Enabled” box next to “HTTPS Everywhere”, and tick it back.

Click on “background page” in the “HTTPS Everywhere” block, and select the “Console” tab. If you see an error message in red, there was an error in your rules; fix it and try again. Otherwise your rules are working.

¹  <sub>The default Chrome profile directory is located at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` under Windows and `~/.config/google-chrome/Default` under Linux</sub>

Comment: Uupon making the change to extension files, newer versions of Chrome (mine is 41) disable the extension with a message -- "“This extension may have been corrupted" and provide a Repair option to download/ install it afresh (https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/187443?hl=en).

Comment: @andy Yes, Google has added another layer of annoyance. You need to move the extension outside the Chrome directory and install it from there. I've updated the answer, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Is there any way to add custom rules through some graphic interface, something similar to <chrome://net-internals/#hsts>?

Comment: @FranklinYu Yes, there is. Click on the button for this extension. The point of this question was what happens below that interface.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you. I didn't notice that the link to add custom rules *only* appears in *HTTPS* pages, so I need to create the rule on target site instead of source site (which actually makes sense). By the way, is there any way to list (index) all the custom rules added by that "add custom rule" link? And even to change/delete some rules?

Answer (score 2):

- In your OS, go to the folder where the HTTPS Everywhere extension was
  installed. On Windows, that's
  `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp\VERSION`
  (replace `VERSION`, of course).
- Put the XML file(s) in the `rules` subfolder.
- Edit **rule_list.js** and add the new file(s) to the list, like this
  (`THEFILE.xml` is the new ruleset):

  `var rule_list = ["rules/default.rulesets","rules/THEFILE.xml"];`
- Restart Chrome.

Copied from [here](http://pastebin.com/cFNzUmiZ) and slightly altered.